# Changing the font size of certain chapters in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, fontsize

I'm writing my thesis according to my university's rules. According to that I want to change the font size (to 14 pt) of the main chapters in the TOC.  When I make the change with `\renewcommand\cftchapfont{fontsize{14pt}{0pt} \mdseries}`, it changes also the other parts like abstract, acknowledgement, etc. But, I only want to change the chapters "1.INTRODUCTION, 2. METHOD, 3. CONCLUSION". I do not want to change the parts that I defined as `\invisiblechapter{}`. Can anybody help with this problem? You can find the MWE below. Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[turkish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm,top=2.8cm,bottom=2.9cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.7cm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thechapter}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}

%Ana bölüm-alt bölüm başlıklarındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1.25cm}{0pt} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\baselineskip = 12pt

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe} %çerçeveyi gösterme
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Çizelge} }

\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{\centerline{KAYNAKLAR}}}



\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

%boşluk ayarlama
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%paragraflar arasında bir boş satır bırakma
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt} %Şekil açıklamalarının altındaki boşluk
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{12pt} %Şekil açıklamalarının üstndeki boşluk


\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{times}

%Sayfa tiplerinin tanımları (sayfa numaralandırma, sayfa puntosu, alt üst yazı)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}} % except the center

%Dokümanın "Giriş" kısmından sonraki ana metinde kullanılacak sayfa biçimi
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

%Dokümanın başlangıçtan "Giriş" kısmına kadar olan sayfa düzeni
\fancypagestyle{mainfront}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cfttabindent{0pt} %tablo listesini sola hizalama
\setlength\cftfigindent{0pt} %şekil listesini sola hizalama

%İçindekilerdeki koyu olanları normale çevirme
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont \mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}

%chapter başlığını göstermeme
\newcommand\invisiblechapterx[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\vskip 0.8\baselineskip} %İçindekilerin başında "sayfa" yazma
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \chaptermark{#1}}
\newcommand\invisiblechapter[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \chaptermark{#1}}

%tablo içindeki yazıları sola hizalama
\usepackage{chngpage}

%Kaynaklar kısmındaki numaralandırmanın köşeli parantezlerini kaldırma
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
%Math modunda normal yazmak için
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
%İçindekilerdeki ana bölümlere nokta ekleme
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

%İçindekiler ve diğer listelere "Sayfa" yazısı eklemek için
\usepackage{afterpage}

%Satır boşlukları
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{paralist} %maddelendirme için(compactitem)
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%Şekil altyazılarını (1den fazla satıra sahip) hizalamak için
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[font=singlespacing]{caption} %Şekil-Çizelge açıklamasını tek satır aralığı yapma

%İçindekiler boşluk ayarlama
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0pt}

%LOT boşluk ayarlama
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}

%LOF boşluk ayarlama
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\invisiblechapterx{ÖZET}
\invisiblechapter{ABSTRACT}
\invisiblechapter{TEŞEKKÜR}
\newpage
\singlespacing

\renewcommand\contentsname{\hfill\hfill\bfseries\normalsize İÇİNDEKİLER\hfill}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize ŞEKİLLERİN LİSTESİ \hfill}
\renewcommand\listtablename{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize ÇİZELGELERİN LİSTESİ \hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

%İçindekiler başlığındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-13pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{İÇİNDEKİLER} %İçindekiler satırı

\tableofcontents %İçindekiler

\addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Şekil}~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{Çizelge}~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\vskip 0.8\baselineskip}}     %İçindekiler ve diğer listelere "Sayfa" yazısı ekleme


\newpage
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-13pt} %LOT başlığındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ÇİZELGELERİN LİSTESİ}
\listoftables %Çizelge Listesi

\newpage

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-13pt}%LOF başlığındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ŞEKİLLERİN LİSTESİ}
\listoffigures %Şekil Listesi
\newpage
\pagestyle{main}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\blindtext
\chapter{METHOD}
\blindtext
\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\blindtext


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem asdasdfsdg.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define

```
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\Large\mdseries}
```

and set `normalsize` each time you add a personal info in the TOC.

So, your definitions of `\invisiblechapterx` and `\invisiblechapterx` must contain

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize #1}
```

and each time you add a line manually in the TOC (for example):

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize İÇİNDEKİLER}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[turkish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm,top=2.8cm,bottom=2.9cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.7cm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thechapter}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}

%Ana bölüm-alt bölüm başlıklarındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1.25cm}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\baselineskip = 12pt

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe} %çerçeveyi gösterme
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Çizelge} }

\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{\centerline{KAYNAKLAR}}}



\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

%boşluk ayarlama
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%paragraflar arasında bir boş satır bırakma
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt} %Şekil açıklamalarının altındaki boşluk
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{12pt} %Şekil açıklamalarının üstndeki boşluk


\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{times}

%Sayfa tiplerinin tanımları (sayfa numaralandırma, sayfa puntosu, alt üst yazı)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}} % except the center

%Dokümanın "Giriş" kısmından sonraki ana metinde kullanılacak sayfa biçimi
\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

%Dokümanın başlangıçtan "Giriş" kısmına kadar olan sayfa düzeni
\fancypagestyle{mainfront}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[R]{\normalfont\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cfttabindent{0pt} %tablo listesini sola hizalama
\setlength\cftfigindent{0pt} %şekil listesini sola hizalama

%İçindekilerdeki koyu olanları normale çevirme
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\Large\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}

%chapter başlığını göstermeme
\newcommand\invisiblechapterx[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\vskip 0.8\baselineskip} %İçindekilerin başında "sayfa" yazma
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize #1}%
    \chaptermark{#1}}
\newcommand\invisiblechapter[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize #1}%
    \chaptermark{#1}}

%tablo içindeki yazıları sola hizalama
\usepackage{chngpage}

%Kaynaklar kısmındaki numaralandırmanın köşeli parantezlerini kaldırma
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
%Math modunda normal yazmak için
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
%İçindekilerdeki ana bölümlere nokta ekleme
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

%İçindekiler ve diğer listelere "Sayfa" yazısı eklemek için
\usepackage{afterpage}

%Satır boşlukları
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{paralist} %maddelendirme için(compactitem)
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%Şekil altyazılarını (1den fazla satıra sahip) hizalamak için
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage[font=singlespacing]{caption} %Şekil-Çizelge açıklamasını tek satır aralığı yapma

%İçindekiler boşluk ayarlama
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0pt}

%LOT boşluk ayarlama
\renewcommand\cfttabafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}

%LOF boşluk ayarlama
\renewcommand\cftfigafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\invisiblechapterx{ÖZET}
\invisiblechapter{ABSTRACT}
\invisiblechapter{TEŞEKKÜR}
\newpage
\singlespacing

\renewcommand\contentsname{\hfill\hfill\bfseries\normalsize İÇİNDEKİLER\hfill}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize ŞEKİLLERİN LİSTESİ \hfill}
\renewcommand\listtablename{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize ÇİZELGELERİN LİSTESİ \hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

%İçindekiler başlığındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-13pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize İÇİNDEKİLER} %İçindekiler satırı

\tableofcontents %İçindekiler

\addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Şekil}~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{Çizelge}~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Sayfa}\vskip 0.8\baselineskip}}     %İçindekiler ve diğer listelere "Sayfa" yazısı ekleme


\newpage
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-13pt} %LOT başlığındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize ÇİZELGELERİN LİSTESİ}
\listoftables %Çizelge Listesi

\newpage

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-13pt}%LOF başlığındaki boşluğu ayarlama
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize ŞEKİLLERİN LİSTESİ}
\listoffigures %Şekil Listesi
\newpage
\pagestyle{main}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\blindtext
\chapter{METHOD}
\blindtext
\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\blindtext


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem asdasdfsdg.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used     \renewcommand\cftchapfont{\fontsize{14pt}{0pt} \mdseries} instead of     \renewcommand\cftchapfont{\LARGE \mdseries}. Thank you for your help. This worked perfectly! @karlkoeller

Comment: @FatihGÜLEÇ Happy to help. Remember that you can accept (and upvote) the answer, if it helped you. ;-)